# Internet connection arrives over VLAN, how to connect in OpenBSD

Tags: networking, vlan, openbsd

I'm trying to replace my providers router with an OpenBSD box. Unfotunately, the internet connection arrives in a VLAN. I've found a simple guide [here](https://blog.martinschultz.dk/posts/2018-12-08-egen-router-hos-hiper/) for how to do this exact procedure for my provider when using an Edgerouter X, but am very new to OpenBSD, and don't know how to deal with it. Don't worry about the Danish text, the entire configuration is shown in the two screenshots, which are of the Edgerouter interface in English.

I've tried creating an /etc/hostname.vlan101 file following part of [this](http://www.weirdnet.nl/openbsd/tweakfiber/) guide, but it's not quite the same setup, since my connection is not over PPPoE. So far, no luck.

My current hostname.if files are:

.vlan101:

```
dhcp vnetid 101 parent em0
```

.em0:

```
up
```

Does anyone have experience connecting to a VLAN from OpenBSD? I'm guessing that it coming from my ISP doesn't make too much of a difference, but I just can't find any documentation on how to do this.

My ISPs router is set up like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCv5X.jpg

Comment: It sounds like the ISP is just using Ethernet? I've never seen it done like this from an ISP, but it should work the same as any given VLAN use. You'd need to configure the interface that the ISP traffic comes in on for the same VLAN tag as they are tagging their traffic with. See here for details: https://man.openbsd.org/vlan.4

Comment: I've tried. Added current config to question.

Comment: That looks like it is a DSL based tech, which means that is a modem/router combo which first translates an ATM signal to Ethernet and then uses IPoE. You’ll be able to replace the router portion, but you’d still need that ATM translation in place to make use of the Ethernet, otherwise the OpenBSD box will have no clue how to handle the incoming signal from the ISP. In short, you can’t just replace that with a simple router because it isn’t just a simple router.

Comment: `hostname.if` commands are evaluated in sequence, and issued one line at a time. Try putting `dhcp` on a separate line, _after_ configuring the VLAN, i.e., `vnetid` and `parent` on the first line and then `dhcp` on the second.